# Load music files on my iphone application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, programming-languages

Hello all this is my first post here
i have been working in an iphone application it sound like a small music instrument
i've used this code to load my music notes :

```
// get the path of the sound file
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"do"
                                                      ofType:@"mp3"];

// create a URL with the given path
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundPath];

// initialize the AVAudioPlayer with the sound file
btn_do = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                                   error:nil];
[fileURL release];
```

and so on for all other notes (re,me,fa,sol,la,ci)

my question :
is this method right because i have to write this code almost 16 times is there any better or stay like I am.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence the code is right.  If you want to set up multiple notes, the easiest way to make this more efficient is to create a method you can run for each note.  So, create a new method that takes a string and returns a new AVAudioPlayer item:

```
- (AVAudioPlayer *)getNoteFromFilename:(NSString *)name {
  NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name
                                                  ofType:@"mp3"];
  NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
  AVAudioPlayer *note = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                                  error:nil] autorelease];
  return note;
}
```

(Note I have swapped the NSURL method for a convenience, autorelease one which removes the need to separately release it.  We are also returning an autoreleased object `note`, as per convention)

You can then call this method, as follows:

```
btn_do = [self getNoteFromFilename:@"do"];
btn_re = [self getNoteFromFilename:@"re"];
```

and so on!...

Edit: next challenge - try sticking them in an array and so you just have one variable to look after!  You could make the index in the array correspond to the 'tag' property of each different button that calls a note...

Comment: Hello first off all thanks for ur answer
i wrote ur code and it is work properly without error and the xcode "Succeeded" but if i touch button nothing happened and the simulator jump me to the code again in this case I put btn_do = [self getNoteFromFilename:@"do"]; in viewDidLoad why this happened ?
but if I put btn_do = [self getNoteFromFilename:@"do"]; inside the buttonPressed it work but not normal every 5 touches 1 will make sound 
this is my ButtonPressed action:
if(sender == b_do){
NSLog(@"Pointer in do");     [btn_do prepareToPlay];
[btn_do play];
btn_do.currentTime = 0;
thank u again.

Comment: sounds like your btn_do is not being retained.  Call [btn_do retain] in viewDidLoad, or if you're using @property (retain) in .h file, use self.btn_do = [self getNoteFromFilename:] to trigger the retain.

Comment: hey thank u all work properly ur ideas are awesome i used self.btn_do = [self getNoteFromFilename:]; and it succeeded 100% thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Give the notes systematic names and write a loop for this. Maybe you can do this with a list.